# How can I install Front Page server extensions in IIS 6

Tags: iis, frontpage

Sorry guys, Microsoft don't provide much in the line of documentation for installing front page server extensions.

How is it done?

Comment: Voted to close, belongs on serverfault...

Comment: @Lucero: tagging is not the same as voting to close!  Use the `close` link.  Also, have a look at this disucssion on meta http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4128/change-the-belongs-on-serverfault-tag-when-a-question-is-moved-to-serverfault/4211#4211

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to **Add/Remove Programs** in the **Control Panel** and click the
button for **Add/Remove Windows Components**. Within that area, drill down to:

**Application Server > Details > Internet Information Services > Details and
check FrontPage 2002 Server Extensions.**

You may need your Windows Server CD at this point.

*please note that if you have x64 R2 version of windows server 2003 SP2
you need to download it separately.*

Comment: Done that - still doesn't work, oh well, not that important, I'll update the site using FTP